# Running many `pip install -r requirements.txt` concurrently

Tags: python, pip

I'd like to test multiple python projects concurrently. Each project is located in specific directory. Part of the testing is setting up a virtualenv with python packages (via `pip install -r requirements.txt`). Each project has its respective `requirements.txt`.

Each project gets its own virtualenv (`virtualenv -p $PYTHON_VER ./.env` + `source .env/bin/active` + `pip install -r requirements.txt`).

Is it safe to run many of these `pip install`s concurrently given that the downloaded packages are cached (`pip cache dir` tells me the global cache is at `~/.cache/pip`) or would I need to disable the pip cache (`--no-cache-dir`) for parallel runs of `pip install`?

Answer (score 0):

Since cache dir is only used to keep a local copy of the dependencies that would speed up your installation process and reducing unnecessary downloads you can run without `--no-cache-dir`.

Take look at official [documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/caching/).

Update: There was an issue with Concurrency that was fixed in pip [23.3.1](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/12361#issuecomment-1773788836)

Comment: The question is: is it safe to run without `--no-cache-dir`? The documentation doesn't provide any detail around that question which is why I asked here.

Comment: It is not completely safe as stated in [Avoiding caching](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/caching/#avoiding-caching) but in most of the cases it works fine.

Comment: That section describes a different case for which a Python wheel was created instead of a C extension and subsequent installations use that Python wheel instead. That's not related to concurrency/thread safety, at least as far as I can see.